# Committing a set of svn file/directory actions in a single check-in

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I’ve recently decided to re-structure my svn repositories. This job includes lots of file/directory actions (renaming, copying, moving and deleting) in my repository. By default, each action is required to be committed in the context of a check-in. Is there any method to commit lots of these actions in a single check-in? I use TortoiseSVN and Collabnet Subversion 1.6.x.

Comment: Local move, copy or delete is not supposed to be done in a separated commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TortoiseSVN has 2 different tools to work with:

- SVN windows explorer, and there the integrated TortoiseSVN menu.
- TortoiseSVN repository browser.

The repository browser is a UI tool that works directly on the repository, and it does not know when you "begin and end a transaction". So each command is a commit in itself, if a commit is necessary. I do not know any possibility to say for example.

- I declare now the start of a commit session.
- I do then change something, move files, rename directories, ...
- I then finish my commit session.

When you work with the TortoiseSVN windows menu integrated into your windows explorer, you first have to checkout the whole repository. Then you may work locally for some time, use the SVN variations for rename, move and copy, and after some time, commit all your changes at once.

The command line version allows you both things, but it behaves the same. From the [documentation for `move`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn-book.html#svn.ref.svn.c.move):

> This command moves files or directories in your working copy or in the repository. ... Move a file in the repository (this is an immediate commit, so it requires a commit message):

```
$ svn move -m "Move a file" http://svn.red-bean.com/repos/foo.c \
                            http://svn.red-bean.com/repos/bar.c
```

So even when you write a batch file for doing all the stuff, and call that, each `svn move` (and `svn copy` ...) has to have a commit message in itself, if you use the variant that works directly on the repository.

So there is no option to restructure your repository (with the repository browser only) with a single commit. You have to check out the whole repository (at least the part you want to restructure), do your `svn something` commands locally, and commit then at the end. This has the disadvantage that you have a lot of network traffic, you need some place locally, and it costs much more time. But this is the only way to have a single commit.

Perhaps there could be an option with `svnadmin`, but that has a lot of disadvantages in itself.

Comment: Checking out the whole repository is the way. Moving stuff inside working copy is done with drag-drop with right mouse button.

Comment: @mliebelt: It seems that Zerkms and dialecticus are right. When dragging and dropping files by right click, TortoiseSVN allows you to do a set of actions (move, copy, rename) and then commit all the changes within a single check in. Please revise your answer or add another answer to cover this info. Then I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I have added more documentation to the distinction between working in the repository browser or on your local copy. I hope it is now clear what the difference is.

Comment: So, you should remove such false info from your answer: “So no, there is no option to restructure your repository (only) with a single commit”

Comment: Have corrected it. In my opinion, this is a bug in subversion, because to restructure the repository, there should be a tool to do it on the repository (only), so without checking out everything. Example: You have 50  tags (with your content of the distro, each 10 GB big), and want to rename them in one commit. Not so easy to do it well locally ...